# MMX operation (add 16bit is not done)

Tags: c, pixel, mmx

I got some vectors containing unsigned chars that represent pixels from a frame.
I got this function working without the MMX improvement, but I frustrated whit MMX that doesnt work ... So:

I need to add two unsigned chars (the sum need to be done as a 16bit instead of a 8bit cause unsigned char goes from 0-255 as known) and divide them by two (shift right 1). The code I have done so far is below, but the values are wrong, the adds_pu16 doesnt add the 16bit just 8:

```
  MM0 = _mm_setzero_si64();        //all zeros
  MM1 = TO_M64(lv1+k);             //first 8 unsigned chars
  MM2 = TO_M64(lv2+k);             //second 8 unsigned chars

  MM3 =_mm_unpacklo_pi8(MM0,MM1);  //get first 4chars from MM1 and add Zeros
  MM4 =_mm_unpackhi_pi8(MM0,MM1);  //get last 4chars from MM1 and add Zeros

  MM5 =_mm_unpacklo_pi8(MM0,MM2);  //same as above for line 2
  MM6 =_mm_unpackhi_pi8(MM0,MM2);

  MM1 = _mm_adds_pu16(MM3,MM5);    //add both chars as a 16bit sum (255+255 max range)
  MM2 = _mm_adds_pu16(MM4,MM6);

  MM3 = _mm_srai_pi16(MM1,1);      //right shift (division by 2)
  MM4 = _mm_srai_pi16(MM2,1);

  MM1 = _mm_packs_pi16(MM3,MM4);   //pack the 2 MMX registers into one

  v2 = TO_UCHAR(MM1);              //put results in the destination array
```

---

New developments:
Thanks for that king_nak!!
I wrote a simple version of what I am trying to do:

---

```
int main()
{
char A[8]={255,155,2,3,4,5,6,7};
char B[8]={255,155,2,3,4,5,6,7};
char C[8];
char D[8];
char R[8];

__m64* pA=(__m64*) A;

__m64* pB=(__m64*) B;

__m64* pC=(__m64*) C;

__m64* pD=(__m64*) D;

__m64* pR=(__m64*) R;

_mm_empty();

__m64 MM0 = _mm_setzero_si64();

__m64 MM1 = _mm_unpacklo_pi8(*pA,MM0);

__m64 MM2 = _mm_unpackhi_pi8(*pA,MM0);

__m64 MM3 = _mm_unpacklo_pi8(*pB,MM0);

__m64 MM4 = _mm_unpackhi_pi8(*pB,MM0);

__m64 MM5 = _mm_add_pi16(MM1,MM3);

__m64 MM6 = _mm_add_pi16(MM2,MM4);

printf("SUM:\n");

*pC= _mm_add_pi16(MM1,MM3);

*pD= _mm_add_pi16(MM2,MM4);

for(int i=0; i<8; i++) printf("\t%d ", (C[i])); printf("\n");

for(int i=0; i<8; i++) printf("\t%d ", D[i]); printf("\n");

printf("DIV:\n");

*pC= _mm_srai_pi16(MM5,1);

*pD= _mm_srai_pi16(MM6,1);

for(int i=0; i<8; i++) printf("\t%d ", (C[i])); printf("\n");

for(int i=0; i<8; i++) printf("\t%d ", D[i]); printf("\n");

MM1= _mm_srai_pi16(MM5,1);    
MM2= _mm_srai_pi16(MM6,1);

printf("Final Result:\n");
*pR= _mm_packs_pi16(MM1,MM2);
for(int i=0; i<8; i++) printf("\t%d ", (R[i])); printf("\n");

return(0);
}
```

---

And the results are:

SUM:

```
-2  1   54  1   4   0   6   0 

8   0   10  0   12  0   14  0
```

DIV:

```
-1  0   -101    0   2   0   3   0 

4   0   5   0   6   0   7   0
```

Final Result:

```
127     127     2   3   4   5   6   7
```

Well the small numbers are ok while the big numbers which give 127 are wrong. This is a problem, what am I doing wrong :s

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but doesn't srai sign-extend the result? Ok, adding two 8bit uints together will need 9bits at most, so this isn't an issue here.

Comment: Since you're processing 16 bytes at a time why not use SSE rather MMX ?

Comment: Cause the requirements are to use MMX :s
Whit SSE I could do with one step the average between two values and that is to easy :S

Comment: Unfortunately, the arithmetic shift instruction you're using is SSE2... So if the requirement is in fact MMX only, this won't work. If you can at least use 3dnow or SSE instructions, you should go for PAVGB to calculate the average between 8 values.

Comment: Sorry, forget what I said. PSRAW is available in MMX. Looked in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found the problem:
The arguments of the unpack instructions are in the wrong order. If you look at the registers as a whole, it looks like the individual chars are zero-extended to shorts, but in fact, they are zero-*padded*. Just swap around mm0 and the other register in each case and it should work.

Also, you don't need saturated add, a normal PADDW is sufficient. The maximum value you will get is 0xff+0xff=0x01fe, which doesn't have to be saturated.

**Edit:** What's more, PACKSSWB doesn't quite do what you want. PACKUSWB is the correct instruction, saturation will get you wrong results.

Here's a solution (Also replaced the shifts with logical ones and used different pseudo-registers in some places):

```
mm0=pxor(mm0,mm0) =[00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00]
mm1 =[a0,10,ff,18,7f,f0,ff,cc]
mm2 =[c0,20,ff,00,70,26,ff,01]
mm3=punpcklbw(mm1,mm0) =[00a0,0010,00ff,0018]
mm4=punpckhbw(mm1,mm0) =[007f,00f0,00ff,00cc]
mm5=punpcklbw(mm2,mm0) =[00c0,0020,00ff,0000]
mm6=punpckhbw(mm2,mm0) =[0070,0026,00ff,0001]
mm5=paddw(mm3,mm5) =[0160,0030,01fe,0018]
mm6=paddw(mm4,mm6) =[00ef,0116,01fe,00cd]
mm3=psrlwi(mm5,1) =[00b0,0018,00ff,000c]
mm4=psrlwi(mm6,1) =[0077,008b,00ff,0066]
mm1=packuswb(mm3,mm4) =[b0,18,ff,0c,77,8b,ff,66]
```

Answer (score 4):

You should switch the operands in the `_mm_unpacklo_pi8` calls. As you do it, the value bytes are in the higher bytes of the word (e.g. `AB` and `00` packed to `AB00`). After addition and shifting, the values will be greater then `0x7F`, und thus saturated to that value by the pack instruction.

With switched operands, the math is done on values like `00AB`, and the result will fit into a signed byte.

**UPATE:**
After your additional info, I see that the problem is with the `_mm_packs_pi16`. This is the assembly instruction `packsswb`, which will *saturate signed* bytes. E.g. Values > 127 will be set to 127. `(255+255)>>1` is 255, and `(155+155)>>1` is 155...
Use `_mm_packs_pu16` instead. This treats the values as unsigned bytes, and you get the desired results (255/155).

Comment: Doesn't that lose you all the averages between 0x7f and 0xff? For example, add 0xa0 and 0xc0. Hi-extended, this gives 0xa000 and 0xc000, respectively. 0xa000 + 0xc000 = 0x16000, which will be truncated to 0x6000 (or saturated to 0xffff if you use saturated add). Shift, and you get 0x30, which is not the correct result.

Comment: I have done more work on it and posted above... still don't know what is wrong.

Comment: I have changed from the signed to unsigned packing and it is still wrong :s
Result:
-1  -101  2  3  4  5  6  7

Comment: That are the correct results, as -1 == 255, and -101 == 155. You have only a problem with signed/unsigned and word/byte display. Try `unsigned char x = R[0]`, it will give you 255. (also you could write `R[i]&0xff` at you output loop)

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, you don't need a 16 bit intermediate to calculate the average of two 8 bit values.  The formulation:

```
(a >> 1) + (b >> 1) + (a & b & 1)
```

gives the correct result with only 8 bit intermediates necessary.  Perhaps you can utilise this to improve your throughput, if you have 8 bit vector instructions available.

Comment: I tried that approach also but in MMX Instruction Set there is no shifting instructions for 8bit, only for 16/32/64bit

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9fcy11x.aspx

Comment: @Paiva: Note that you can emulate 8 bit logical shifts by masking each byte `& 0xfe` before a wider shift.